# Gulp not including all javascript files

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I am developing a web application using the MEAN framework and gulp for minification of the files. However, the application does not work because there are lots of "is not a function, got undefined" when I inspect the navigator console. When I read the app.min.js file which is generated with gulp, I can't find most of javascripts files (controllers, services and so on).

The folder structure that I am using for the client is the following:

```
client/
├── app.min.js
├── app.min.js.map
├── controllers
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── login_controller.js
│   │   └── register_controller.js
│   ├── home
│   │   └── home_controller.js
│   ├── navigation
│   │   └── navigation_controller.js
│   └── profile
│       └── profile_controller.js
├── directives
│   └── navigation.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── services
│   ├── authentication.js
│   └── data.js
└── views
    ├── auth
    │   ├── login
    │   │   └── login.html
    │   └── register
    │       └── register.html
    ├── home
    │   └── home.html
    ├── navigation
    │   └── navigation.html
    └── profile
        └── profile.html
```

This the the gulp file which I am using:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var watch = require("gulp-watch");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var ngHtml2Js = require("gulp-ng-html2js");

gulp.task("scripts", function() {
  gulp.src([
    "./client/**/*.js",
    "!./client/app.min.js"
  ]).pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(concat("./app.min.js"))
      .pipe(uglify({mangle: true}))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("client"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("client"));
});

gulp.task("watch", function() {
  watch(["./client/**/*.js", "!./client/**/*.test.js", "!./client/app.min.js"], function() {
    gulp.start("scripts");
  });
});

gulp.task("default", ["scripts", "watch"]);
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This is the generated app.min.js file:

```
!function(){function t(t,e){t.when("/",{templateUrl:"views/home/home.html",controller:"homeCtrl",controllerAs:"vm"}).when("/register",{templateUrl:"views/register/register.html",controller:"registerCtrl",controllerAs:"vm"}).when("/login",{templateUrl:"views/login/login.html",controller:"loginCtrl",controllerAs:"vm"}).when("/profile",{templateUrl:"views/profile/profile.html",controller:"profileCtrl",controllerAs:"vm"}).otherwise({redirectTo:"/"}),e.html5Mode(!0)}function e(t,e,n){t.$on("$routeChangeStart",function(t,o,r){"/profile"!==e.path()||n.isLoggedIn()||e.path("/")})}angular.module("app",["ngRoute"]),angular.module("app").config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",t]).run(["$rootScope","$location","authentication",e])}(),function(){function t(){return{restrict:"EA",templateUrl:"/views/navigation/navigation.html",controller:"navigationCtrl as navvm"}}angular.module("app").directive("navigation",t)}(),function(){function t(t,e){var n=function(t){e.localStorage["token"]=t},o=function(){return e.localStorage["token"]},r=function(){var t,n=o();return n?(t=n.split(".")[1],t=e.atob(t),t=JSON.parse(t),t.exp>Date.now()/1e3):!1},i=function(){if(r()){var t=o(),n=t.split(".")[1];return n=e.atob(n),n=JSON.parse(n),{email:n.email,name:n.name}}},l=function(e){return t.post("/api/register",e).success(function(t){n(t.token)})},a=function(e){return t.post("/api/login",e).success(function(t){n(t.token)})},c=function(){e.localStorage.removeItem("token")};return{currentUser:i,saveToken:n,getToken:o,isLoggedIn:r,register:l,login:a,logout:c}}angular.module("app").service("authentication",t),t.$inject=["$http","$window"]}(),function(){function t(t,e){var n=function(){return t.get("/api/profile",{headers:{Authorization:"Bearer "+e.getToken()}})};return{getProfile:n}}angular.module("app").service("appData",t),t.$inject=["$http","authentication"]}(),function(){function t(t,e){var n=this;n.credentials={name:"",email:"",password:""},n.onSubmit=function(){console.log("Submitting registration"),e.register(n.credentials).error(function(t){alert(t)}).then(function(){t.path("profile")})}}angular.module("app").controller("registerCtrl",t),t.$inject=["$location","authentication"]}(),function(){function t(){console.log("Home controller is running")}angular.module("app").controller("homeCtrl",t)}(),function(){function t(t,e){var n=this;n.user={},e.getProfile().success(function(t){n.user=t}).error(function(t){console.log(t)})}angular.module("app").controller("profileCtrl",t),t.$inject=["$location","appData"]}();
//# sourceMappingURL=app.min.js.map
```

Comment: When you say you get *some* files, which ones do you get? Ditch the uglify call temporarily, if that will help you determine which is which. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502678/gulp-uglify-and-sourcemaps) may be helpful to you. I suspect it has something to do with your first `gulp.dest()` call after `uglify`, but I'm not positive. Try removing it and see if it starts working.

Comment: I have tried what you have said but it don't work. I have updated the question with the app.min.js file. As you can see, you can find references to some controllers but does not appear the declaration of it (for example, navigationCtrl).

Comment: Finally I have found the problem. Gulp is not including some of the controllers because I have forgotten to call the function. For example, I use `(function() {...Controller...});` instead of `(function() {...Controller...})();`

Comment: Ah. Yeah, I believe `uglify` will try to eliminate dead code, and I suppose if you aren't using it, then away it goes.