# Gulp: Generate sourcemaps for both minified and non-minified scripts

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, uglifyjs, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm new to gulp and have run into a problem which probably is a pretty common scenario. What I'm trying todo is compiling typescript into javascript, creating a sourcemap for it and then running uglify. I would like to have a sourcemap for the ugliyfied as well as the non uglified js.

What I'm trying to achive is the following file structure:

```
framework.js
framework.js.map < this won't work
framework.min.js
framework.min.js.map
```

This is my gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
ts = require("gulp-typescript")
sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps')
rename = require('gulp-rename');

var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");


gulp.task('typescript', function(){
    tsProject.src()
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(tsProject()).js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Write sourcemap for non-minified version
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
    .pipe(uglify()) // Code will fail here 
    .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Write sourcemap for minified version.
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});

gulp.task('default', ['typescript']);
```

As you can see, I'm running sourcemaps.write() twice to get the two different files. This gives me an error

```
tream.js:74                                                                        
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.                                  
  ^ GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript                                       
at createError     (C:\Users\alexa\Dropbox\code\Web\mhadmin\framework\node_modules\gulp-uglify\lib\create-error.js:6:14)
```

Leaving out the first one of the sourcemap.write() calls will result in a correct sourcemap for the minified version of the file.

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: This is not exactly a duplicate of [gulp: uglify and sourcemaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502678/gulp-uglify-and-sourcemaps) as I need to write multiple sourcemaps with multiple calls to gulp.dest()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp: uglify and sourcemaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502678/gulp-uglify-and-sourcemaps)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that after the first `.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))` you have two files in your stream:

```
framework.js
framework.js.map
```

You write those two files to the file system (which is fine), but then you try to run `uglify()` on both of them. Since your `framework.js.map` file is not a JavaScript file and doesn't contain valid JavaScript code the `uglify()` plugin throws up.

After you have written `framework.js.map` to the file system there is really no reason to keep that file in the stream anymore. The vinyl file object for `framework.js` still has a `.sourceMap` property that carries all the transformations so far, meaning you can just remove the `framework.js.map` file from the stream.

The [`gulp-filter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-filter) plugin let's you do just that:

```
var filter = require('gulp-filter');

gulp.task('typescript', function(){
  return tsProject.src()
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(tsProject()).js
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
   .pipe(filter('**/*.js')) // only let JavaScript files through here
   .pipe(uglify())
   .pipe(rename({suffix:'.min'}))
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
   .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

After `.pipe(filter('**/*.js'))` only the `framework.js` file will be in the stream and `uglify()` won't throw up anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sven! I just figured out exactly the same (my code is even identical to yours) solution and it works!

Comment: @Sven : isn't uglifyJS supposed to have a outSourceMap option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41722432/sourcemaps-to-uglified-script-dont-work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like kind of hack, but it works

```
gulp.src('TypeScript/Test.ts')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsOptions)).js
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/test'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/test'));
```

The magic is in `plumber`. Plumber prevents stopping proccess on exception. But the main interest why exception happens. So, it's pretty clear. In your code you create sourcemap via `.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.')) // Write sourcemap for non-minified version` and then try to uglify it. And yes, sourcemap is not js, and exception happens. With `plumber` this exception ignores and you achive your goal.

But I could have figured out something wrong, I recommend you to find more true-way solution.

Comment: This will work but, like you said: it's a bit of a hack. But you got me on the write track. The key is to get rid of the *.map files in the pipeline before continuing. See SvenSchoenung's answer.